# Bokeh - Dynamic allocation of value to legend in streaming chart

Tags: python, dynamic, legend, bokeh

I have a streaming chart where the scores are updated in realtime. I am plotting a graph to show the value as a line graph for Student X.
I want the legend to be updated dynamically(either show as legend in the chart or display the name of the student on mouseover).
Below is the code which works perfectly fine without "legend" but when I try to add the legend I get the below error.

How can I show the value dynamically using legend or using mouseover event or if possible any other way?

Code:

```
p = figure(title="Low Percentage", x_axis_label='Time', 
y_axis_label='Low_Perc')
r1 = p.line(x = [], y = [], legend = [], color="firebrick", line_width=2)
ds1 = r1.data_source

@linear()
def update(step):
    test = pd.read_json('c:/scores.csv', orient='columns')
    test2 = pd.read_json( (test['result']).to_json(), orient='index')
    df=test2[['Time','Name','Last','Low','Low_Perc']]
    df2=df.sort_values(by='Low_Perc', ascending=False)
    y = df2['Low_Perc'].iat[0]
    name = df7['Name'].iat[0]
    output_file("lines.html")
    ds1.data['x'].append(step)
    ds1.data['y'].append(y)
    ds1.data['legend'].append(name)
    ds1.trigger('data', ds1.data, ds1.data, ds1.data)
curdoc().add_root(p)
curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 30000)
```

Error:

```
Error thrown from periodic callback: KeyError('legend',)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to interact with *Legend* object is using the [bokeh.models api](https://bokeh.github.io/blog/2017/7/5/idiomatic_bokeh/). As described in [documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/annotations.html#bokeh.models.annotations.Legend.items), Legend object can be created manually, this gives you the possibility to play with the [legend.items](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/annotations.html#bokeh.models.annotations.Legend.items) list to add and remove legendItems in the legend.

Be aware that you need to pass a glyph-renderer to make a link between legendItem and something on the plot. You can get a renderer object by looking in [Plot object p.renderers](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/plots.html#bokeh.models.plots.Plot.renderers) or when [adding a glyph to the figure/plot](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html#bokeh.plotting.figure.Figure.line) as you have done with r1 :

```
r1 = p.line(x = [], y = [], legend = [], color="firebrick", line_width=2)
# r1 is a glyphrenderer
```